# loading .gif before animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating animation using Jquery. it contains many images(.png) and div tags. Some of them are small file size whereas i have biggest of 5mb.

How to display pre-loading(.gif) animation before all the files are downloaded and ready for animation?

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 methods to look into :

- $(document).ready() will be executed only when all the HTML (DOM) for the page is downloaded.
- $(window).load() is called when all the page resources (style, images etc) are downloaded.

[Here you'll find some more details.](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Btw, 5mb for an image to download from a browser it's quite a lot, consider resize them!